# Unidentifiable video modes listed as supported under DOSBox

Tags: graphics, dos, turbo-c++, vga, vesa

I have noticed something rather strange messing around in DOSBox with VGA/VESA programming.

Running the VESA BIOS function 01h, and then printing out the entries of the list pointed to by the value at an offset of 14 into the buffer until -1 is reached prints the following entries:

```
Modes: 100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 10d, 10e, 10f, 110, 111, 112, 113, 114, 115, 116, 117, 150,
151, 152, 153, 160, 161, 162, 165, 170, 171, 172, 175, 190, 191, 192, 207, 209, 20a, 213, 222, 223, 224, 225
```

The code to do this, in TurboC++ for DOS, is:

```
union REGS regs;
struct SREGS sregs;
byte buffer[1024];
word far *modes, far *mptr;
regs.x.ax = 0x4f00;
sregs.es = FP_SEG(buffer);
regs.x.di = FP_OFF(buffer);
int86x(0x10, &regs, &regs, &sregs);
modes = *(word far**)(buffer + 14);
printf("Modes: ");
for(mptr = modes; *mptr != -1; mptr++){
    printf("%02x, ", *mptr);
}
printf("\n");
```

Basically, what I don't understand is what a lot of these modes are. Some of them, e.g. up to 117, I can find documentation for, but for a lot of these, like the 150's and everything past 200, I cannot find any indication of what these modes actually are. Can anyone help me figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

Taken from [VGA/VESA videomodes](http://www.columbia.edu/~em36/wpdos/videomodes.txt):

```
Values for S3 OEM video mode:[18]
201h   640x480x256
202h   800x600x16
203h   800x600x256
204h   1024x768x16
205h   1024x768x256
206h   1280x960x16
207h   1152x864x256 (Diamond Stealth 64)
208h   1280x1024x16
209h   1152x864x32K
20Ah   1152x864x64K (Diamond Stealth 64)
20Bh   1152x864x4G
211h   640x480x64K (Diamond Stealth 24)
211h   640x400x4G  (Diamond Stealth64 Video / Stealth64 Graphics)
212h   640x480x16M (Diamond Stealth 24)
301h   640x480x32K
```

looks like they where **S3 gfx cards** related... IIRC They needed special gfx driver under DOS to work unlike standard VGA/VESA cards which runs natively without any drivers needed (unless you wanted VBE extentions like UNIVBE).

Comment: That would account for some of them, but not all.

Comment: @user2649681 if you want more info try posting this on https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/